# An example for dilation convolution-deconvolution (tensorflow)

Tags: python, tensorflow, deconvolution, conv-neural-network

I am trying to create an autoencoder based on dilated convolutions. I am confused about different suntax and also down/up sampling approches. How we can do it for just one layer which **preserves** the sizes of the input and output?

-by using **tf.nn.atrous_conv2d** and then **tf.nn.atrous_conv2d_transpose**

-by using  **tf.nn.conv2d**  and then **tf.nn.conv2d_transpose**

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used dilation before, but I work with autoencoders based on convolutions. Here is an example of an architecture that takes input size 28x28x1 such as mnist images. Using a stride of 2, the size will be down-sampled to 14x14x1, then to 7x7x1. Then it will be flattened and then decreased to 32, the encoding size. After that, a set of transpose convolution layers, with stride of 2, will increase the size back to 28x28x1.

Here is the code example:

```
def autoencoder_network(x):
encoder_14 = tf.layers.conv2d(x, filters=1, kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)
encoder_7 = tf.layers.conv2d(encoder_14, filters=1,kernel_size=3, strides=2, padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)
flatten_dim = np.prod(encoder_7.get_shape().as_list()[1:])
flat = tf.reshape(encoder_7, [-1, flatten_dim])
code = tf.layers.dense(flat, 32, activation=tf.nn.relu)
hidden_decoder = tf.layers.dense(code, flatten_dim, activation=tf.nn.relu)
decoder_7 = tf.reshape(hidden_decoder, [-1, 7, 7, 1])
decoder_14 = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(decoder_7, 1, 3, strides=2, padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)
output = tf.layers.conv2d_transpose(decoder_14, 1, 3, strides=2, padding='same', activation=tf.nn.relu)
return code, output
```

Answer (score 0):

I did such such as follow. it seems that the size of matrixes are reasonable.
Is it correct?

```
X=tf.random_uniform(shape=(256,256,3),minval=0,maxval=100,dtype=tf.float32,seed=None,name=None)

input2d = tf.reshape(X, [-1,256,256,3])
print(input2d.shape)

dilation_rate=2

in_channels=3
out_channels=32
kernelsize_h=4
kernelsize_w=4

filter = tf.get_variable("filter", [kernelsize_h, kernelsize_w, in_channels, out_channels], dtype=tf.float32,  initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(0, 0.02))
output=tf.nn.atrous_conv2d(input2d, filter, rate=dilation_rate, padding="SAME")
print(output.shape)
filterBack = tf.get_variable("filterBack", [kernelsize_h, kernelsize_w, in_channels,out_channels], dtype=tf.float32, initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(0, 0.02))
output_shape=[1,256,256,3]
reversed=tf.nn.atrous_conv2d_transpose(output,filterBack,output_shape,rate=dilation_rate,padding="SAME")
print(reversed.shape)
```

and the results are:
(1, 256, 256, 3)
(1, 256, 256, 32)
(1, 256, 256, 3)